# How to create an assertion on my playbook?

Tags: ansible

I would like to use the assert function in ansible for a test.

The goal is to check if they are some files and directories that contains the permission 1500, if it is the case than I would like to show the message *fail*

```
- hosts: localhost 
  tasks: 
  - name: Check assertion
    shell: find . -perm 1500
    register: list_files_directories
  - name: Check if file testfile.txt exists 
    assert: 
      that: 
      -   mode =! '1500' in list_files_directories
```

After multiple test,cannot find the right syntax to execute the assertion...

Comment: Did you debug the exact content of `list_file_directories` varialble to see how it looks like ? it should contain a `stdout`(full string output) and `stdout_lines` (list of strings line by line) parameters with the return from your shell command. If I understand correctly what you are doing, you could simply assert that the list of lines from your command has a length of 0. Warning: your current command seems to contains a typo (`perm` => `-perm`)

Comment: compare the line if it is above > 0 would be also enough but want to know if I can do that test by using the assert part to have something clear

Comment: If you want to assert, you have to test that it **is** 0 (i.e. no permissions `1500` exists). It will fail if that test is false. And regarding if you can do it or not: did you actually try it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-builtin-find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) module. For example, given the files

```sh
shell> find . -perm 1500
./file2
```

The tasks below

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: .
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.files|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?mode=='1500'].path"
```

give the list of the files with permissions '1500'

```yaml
    "msg": [
        "file2"
    ]
```

To check if there are any files and directories with the permission 1500 test the length of the list

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: result.files|json_query(query)|length > 0
      vars:
        query: "[?mode=='1500'].path"
```